# android Save canvas as jpg image

Tags: android, image, canvas, save, jpeg

I have this code in saving the canvas into image. here the function in Oncreate
But the saved image is only 1, once I saved another canvas to image, it only overrides the first one. Pleaase Help me. Thank you

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    mTempDir =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + "PixiePhotos" + "/";
    mCurrent = "PXD_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    prepareDirectory();



      save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {try {
                mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBitmap);
                mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
                String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
                File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
                mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutputStream);
                mFileOutputStream.flush();
                mFileOutputStream.close();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
              } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
              }

            }
          });
    }

  private boolean prepareDirectory() {
        try {
          if (makeDirectory()) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sdcard_error), 1000).show();
          return false;
        }
      }

    private boolean makeDirectory() {
        File mTempFile = new File(mTempDir);
        if (!mTempFile.exists()) {
          mTempFile.mkdirs();
        }

        if (mTempFile.isDirectory()) {
          File[] mFiles = mTempFile.listFiles();
          for (File mEveryFile : mFiles) {
            if (!mEveryFile.delete()) {
              //System.out.println(getString(R.string.failed_to_delete) + mEveryFile);
            }
          }
        }
        return (mTempFile.isDirectory());
      }
```

Comment: you cannot save a Canvas, you can save a Bitmap however

Comment: i already got the solution, thanks :) but i have another problem :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909180/android-paint-the-dragged-sticker-on-the-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get timestamp just once, you should take that every time you click save.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {try {
            mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBitmap);
            mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();

            mCurrent = "PXD_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()); + ".jpg";

            String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
            File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
            mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutputStream);
            mFileOutputStream.flush();
            mFileOutputStream.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
          } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
          }

        }
      });
```

Comment: Mr. @Tomasz do you know how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909180/android-paint-the-dragged-sticker-on-the-canvas please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the `String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());` and `mCurrent = "PXD_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";` inside the on click because the oncreate is only called once when the activity is created.